# Installing Elm on Centos 6.9

Tags: node.js, haskell, centos, centos6, elm

I installed `Elm` via `yarn global add elm`. However, whenever I run `elm -v`, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/elm/Elm-Platform/0.18.0/.cabal-sandbox/bin/elm: error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've installed via `yum`, the `haskell-platform` package and the `gmp` package. Unfortunately, I still receive the same error.

Any help in diagnosing this error would greatly be appreciated. Thank you.

---

**EDIT #1**

Checking `ghc`, I see that the version is `7.0.4`. Apparently this is a very old version of `ghc`. I'll see if I can update ghc.

**EDIT #2**

Seems like because I'm on `Centos 6.9`, I'm sol. The `haskell-platform` repo is from 2011. I'll have to find otherwise of building the platform.

Comment: Can you tell us the ghc version you have and maybe reinstall it - if libgmp is missing maybe there is also a path issue that could be fixed by a reinstall

Comment: Alternatively you can install stack and install haskell using `stack setup`, then you can install el by cloning the git repos and using stack/ghc  to build

Comment: I can post a working stack.yaml when I am at home

Comment: Unfortunately, `stack setup` did not work. I'll read up about this command.

Comment: I managed to install stack without any problems a few months ago on a centos machine just follow https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/#how-to-install

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. I installed `stack` and ran `stack setup` successfully. I reinstalled `elm` afterwards. However, still no dice when running `elm -v`.

Comment: You can always try building it from the source https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-platform

Comment: @KurtMueller did my instructions work? if not I'll get myself a docker container and try to make elm on centos work!

Comment: Hi epsilon. I really appreciate your help and should have responded to you sooner. I'm sorry I did not. I actually moved my app to RHEL 7 (since my organization has a cluster of those vms) and use the `haskell-platform` package on that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of instructions to (hopefully) reliably install elm on CentOS

1. remove all previous installations of elm and ghc (we will install a newer ghc)
2. install stack by following the [installation instructions](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/#how-to-install)
3. clone the elm sources:

   ```
   mkdir elm && cd elm
   git clone https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler
   git clone https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-make
   git clone https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-package
   git clone https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-reactor
   git clone https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-repl
   ```
4. put the following `stack.yaml` in the newly created `elm` directory

   ```
   resolver: lts-9.9

   packages:
   - elm-compiler/
   - elm-make/
   - elm-package/
   - elm-compiler/profiling/
   - elm-reactor/
   - elm-repl/
   # Dependency packages to be pulled from upstream that are not in the resolver
   # (e.g., acme-missiles-0.3)
   extra-deps:
   - aeson-pretty-0.7.2
   - binary-0.7.6.1
   - ghc-time-alloc-prof-0.1.0
   - http-client-0.4.31.2
   - http-client-tls-0.2.4.1
   - http-types-0.8.6
   - vector-0.11.0.0
   - primitive-0.6.1.0
   - websockets-0.9.8.2

   # Override default flag values for local packages and extra-deps
   flags: {}

   # Extra package databases containing global packages
   extra-package-dbs: []
   ```
5. `stack setup` (might take some time)
6. `stack build` (see above - grab a coffee)
7. `stack install` (do not forget to add the install location (usually `~/.local/bin`) to your `$PATH`
8. `elm -v` should work now

Comment: Hi epsilon, thank you for my help. See my above comment. If you test this this and it works, I'll mark this as answered. Thank you again for taking time to help a fellow dev out.